# ROR sending email based on account number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

We're using Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3.2 We use AS/400 for our database. We've tried using Active Record for this before, and it doesn't want to work because of our versions of Ruby and Rails being older combined with getting it to connect with the 400.

We have an online ordering site that you have to have an account set up to access.  Depending on what type of account you are set up as, you might have to have your order approved by someone. I.e. if I am a drop ship account, my distributor has to approve what I'm ordering. The way it had been set up, the distributor wasn't getting any kind of approval email.

We've been trying the line of code below in console, and have it working. If we enter an account number instead of leaving it blank, it returns a list of the email addresses that would be getting the approval email. Fantastic! If it's left blank as shown below, it returns a blank array. Makes sense, we haven't logged in, so it doesn't know our account number yet. When the user logs in, their account number should automatically be substituted in.

```
Contact.find_by_sql ["SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = ‘’”]
```

However, when we add that code snippet into the order.rb file, it returns an error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 4)
```

Clearly, the way we have the line set up isn't right:

```
Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email('Contact.find_by_sql (SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = "30153"')
```

It's just getting confusing... we seem to be going in circles with the errors. We try to fix it, but then we just get new errors that still have to do with that line.

The deliver_order_distributor_approval_email method is in the **mailer.rb** file below:

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base

##################################################################################
##################################################################################
# NOTE: in all cases, use sanitize_email to ensure nothing goes out by accident. #
##################################################################################
##################################################################################

def order_confirmation_email(recipient_email, from_email, subject, email_details)

    recipient_email = Mailer.sanitize_email(recipient_email)

    # Get the template of the email body from the database and then perform all replacements.
    email_body = Setting.first.email_order_body
    email_details.each {|key, value| email_body.gsub!("##" + key.upcase.gsub("_"," ") + "##", value)}

    recipients      recipient_email
    from                    from_email
    subject             subject
    bcc                     Setting.first[:email_admin_to]

    part :content_type => "text/html",
    :body =>    email_body

    #f=File.open("/var/www/onlineordering.example.com/log/debugger.txt")
   #f.puts get_email = $get_email
   #f.close

end

def order_coastal_notify_email(from_email, subject, email_details)

    # Get the template of the email body from the database and then perform all replacements.
    email_body = Setting.first.email_order_coastal_notify
    email_details.each {|key, value| email_body.gsub!("##" + key.upcase.gsub("_"," ") + "##", value)}

    recipients      Setting.first[:email_order_placed_to]
    from                    from_email
    subject             subject
    bcc                     Setting.first[:email_admin_to]

    part :content_type => "text/html",
    :body =>    email_body

end

def order_distributor_approval_email(recipient_email, from_email, subject, email_details)

    recipient_email = Mailer.sanitize_email(recipient_email)

    # Get the template of the email body from the database and then perform all replacements.
    # We run the attachment and the email body through replacement tags.
    email_body = Setting.first.email_order_attachment_body
    email_attachment_body = Setting.first.email_order_attachment
    email_details.each {|key, value| email_body.gsub!("##" + key.upcase.gsub("_"," ") + "##", value)}
    email_details.each {|key, value| email_attachment_body.gsub!("##" + key.upcase.gsub("_"," ") + "##", value)}

    # If their email is blank, we'll send it to admin.
    recipients      recipient_email.blank? ? Setting.first[:email_admin_to] : recipient_email
    from                    from_email
    subject             subject
    bcc                     Setting.first[:email_order_placed_to]

    part :content_type => "text/html",
    :body =>    email_body

    attachment "application/pdf" do |a|
        a.body = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(email_attachment_body)
        a.filename = "Drop Ship Approval Form.pdf"
    end

end

def order_again_reminder_email(name, recipient_email, from_email, subject)

    recipient_email = Mailer.sanitize_email(recipient_email)

    recipients recipient_email
    from       from_email
    bcc              Setting.first[:email_admin_to]
    subject    subject
    body       :content => Setting.first.email_reminder_body.gsub!(/##NAME##/, name.to_s.titleize)

end

def forgot_password_email(recipient_email, from_email, subject, password)

    recipient_email = Mailer.sanitize_email(recipient_email)

    recipients recipient_email
    from       from_email
    bcc              Setting.first[:email_admin_to]
    subject    subject
    body       :password => password

end

def register_email(recipient_email, from_email, subject, params)

    recipient_email = Mailer.sanitize_email(recipient_email)

    recipients recipient_email
    from       from_email
    bcc              Setting.first[:email_admin_to]
    subject    subject
    body       :params => params

end

private
    def self.sanitize_email(recipient_email)

        # Comma separate multiple email addresses.
        case ENV['RAILS_ENV']
        when 'production'
            recipient_email = recipient_email
        when 'development'
            recipient_email = "John Doe<john@example.com>"
        else
            # This is really the production, since they don't have a true production server
            # should resolve to "dev". 
            recipient_email = recipient_email
        end
        recipient_email
    end
end
```

If the order.rb file would be helpful, I can attach it... it's just kind of lengthy, so I didn't include it in the post. If you have any suggestions as to how to change the mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email line, please let me know.. I'd really appreciate it! Thank you in advance!

**Edit**

```
Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email ('Contact.find_by_sql SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = "30153"'),"Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation-customer", email_details
```

With this (after some tweaking), we were able to submit an order without any errors, but we aren't getting any emails. Odd. It almost seems like we might be missing some mailer calls or something?

**Edit**
After modifying the script suggested a little, we came up with this...

```
 target_email = Contact.find_by_sql ["SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = ''"]        
Mailer.deliver_order_confirmation_email(target_email, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation-customer", email_details)
```

It "works" without errors - we can log in and submit an order, but still fail to get any email. 
Oddly enough, that snippet returns the error below when ran through the console.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: 37000 (-10) [IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver][DB 2 UDB]SQL0010 - String constant beginning '        ' not delimited.
```

If we put in an account number like below, it runs through and submits.. but still no email. It returns an error on the console, too.

```
target_email = Contact.find_by_sql ["SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 ='30153'"]                        
Mailer.deliver_order_confirmation_email(target_email, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation-customer", email_details)
```

Error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `email_details' for main:Object
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 4)
```

indicates that you have called a method that expects four arguments, but you only provided one.  Here's your method call:

```
Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email('Contact.find_by_sql (SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = "30153"')
```

As written, you've provided one argument: the string `'Contact.find_by_sql (SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = "30153"'`.

When you call the method `Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email`, it eventually passes the arguments it is given to the `order_distributor_approval_email` method you've defined in your `Mailer` class.  That method requires four arguments, but you're only giving it one, hence the error.  You need to provide all four arguments to make the method call work.

**Update:**

You are passing the string `'Contact.find_by_sql SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = "30153"'` as the first argument, so the mailer is trying to treat that string as an email address, which naturally isn't going to work.  Presumably you want to actually call the `find_by_sql` method on `Contact` to get the real email address, in which case you'll want something like this:

```
target_email = Contact.find_by_sql('SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = "30153"').first
Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(target_email, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation-customer", email_details)
```

This should perform the query and attempt to send the email to the first result.  You will need to make further adjustments to send to multiple recipients or to send multiple emails.

Comment: Ah ha ha! We had removed 3 arguments because of one of the errors we were getting that still doesn't make sense. I have edited my post with the updated string and error. Thank you for being so quick to respond! :)

Comment: I tried the update... still no go. I also updated my post. Thank you, Wally! :)